# Django User model customize validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have altered the column 'username' in the User table by using the following south migration

db.alter_column('auth_user', 'username', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(unique=True, max_length=75))

As this change is only at the DB level, my User admin page throws an error when I try to edit something and save.

[image]

How do I override the validation to make the field accept 75 characters at most.

Note:

- I don't want to define custom user model

Answer (score 2):

You can monkey patch `User` model.  Add this line to any of your `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User._meta.get_field('username').max_length = 75
```

**EDIT**: We are so naive. Look at [this app](https://github.com/madssj/django-longer-username-and-email). Turns out there is a lot of places to monkey patch :-)

Comment: I tried it already, didn't work. FYI I am using Django 1.5. Please suggest any other work around.